# Why aren't there displays which explicitly emit certain frequencies?

Tags: display, laser, optics, oled

Rather than building displays that emit RGB, why not build displays that emit certain frequencies instead? What are the technical challenges of doing this?

Comment: It's easier to build three pixels that each emit one wavelength than to build one pixel which emits every wavelength. When was the last time you saw an LED that could vary wildly in wavelength? Probably never. I certainly never have.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think I didn't understand your comment, as I'd consider white LEDs to be exactly that: a single LED emitting all the wavelengths at the same time.

Comment: @jonathanjo Bad wording on my part and I edited it. And unless your definition of a display is just a lamp, an LED that is white all the time isn't going to cut it as the only pixel in a display.

Comment: @DKNguyen, ah yes, post-edit that makes much more sense.

Comment: @jonathanjo A while LEDs most definitely do not emit all frequencies. White LEDs are blue LEDs with yellow phosphorus that converts blue wavelength light to yellow. The combination of the two spectrums happens to pass the white point and the proportions are tuned for the light to appear white. Or some defined color temperature.

Comment: Not to say that isn't a holy grail of sorts, but it would have more applications in antennas than monitors. It would be more like an antenna than any emitter of light we currently have. The technological bar is just so high for a monitor made of optical antennas; I think mass produced graphene is easier.

Comment: @Justme ... of course I mean "human vision spectrum white", and exactly as you say, white LEDs are emitting a mix within that range, and of course it's not a pure flat graph.  But it's much broader than say a blue spike and a yellow spike. [Spectrum at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#/media/File:White_LED.png)

Comment: @Justme I think what you are saying is really not accurate. The spectrum of a white LED does not consist of discreet peaks.

Comment: White LEDs do emit all visible frequencies of light. Also, white LEDs are used as the backlight in most or at least many LCDs. It seems like the main reason displays work as they do is because the human eye has RGB detectors and not other colors.

Comment: I did say "spectrum", I never claimed a white LED containing two monochromatic peaks, even if that is how human eyes work. It would have very poor CRI. Blue LED in them have very narrow peak but not monochromatic. The phosphorus will emit a spectrum of light and combined it will appear white. The CRI can still be bad and approximately equals fluorescent lights, only expensive LED lights can approximate the spectrum of incandescents. Anyway, for a display, you only need 3 channels to reproduce stimulation of 3 receptors.

Comment: @mkeith First error is that human eyes are RGB detectors. No, they have three detectors sensitive to a range of spectrum and they overlap. A white LED does not or does it need to emit all frequencies of light. For a computer display, it just needs to have a spectrum to stimulate the three receptors in a relative way that it looks white, for some definition of white. And the RGB filters then remove parts of the spectrum for the remaining spectrum to appear red, green, or blue to your receptors, for some definition of red, green and blue.

Comment: One word: cost. RGB is cheap and good enough for most applications.

Comment: @Justme the spectrum of white LED lights that you can readily view online and that is published in the datasheets for LED lights shows that it emits all visible wavelengths of light. I have also looked with a diffraction grating and my impression was that the spectrum is very continuous.

Comment: White phosphor LED's are indeed continuous emitters (all frequencies), though they are clearly very very strong in blue and yellow.

Answer (score 3):

What you suggest is not a technical challenge, it's just not needed. The RGB monitor already emits certain frequencies, or rather, a spectrum, and all you need is to stimulate the three receptors at correct proportions.

And actually laser projection systems with monochromatic RGB lasers may exist, as the BT.2020 colour space is defined by three single monochromatic lasers, so these should fulfill your specs.

Computers already usually work in RGB, and for human eyes, any stimulus that recreates the original stimulus for the three different receptors will look equal.

So you don't need monitors that have e.g. 32 channels of different wavelengths in the whole spectrum, you really need only 3.

In comparison to audio, you only need one speaker in a headphone to emit all required frequencies to your ear, because a single speaker can output any waveform with all the required frequencies. So you don't need one speaker per frequency.

And because each pixel requires to control the spectrum how it stimulates three receptors in combination, you need a linear combination of three spectrums. It does not have to be RGB, as long as the end result triggers the receptors in a same way in proportion.

So all the display needs to do is to emit some spectrum of light which trigges the three different receptors with a linear combination of sprectrum to appear to have some required color, and adding up to linear combination of achromatic white.

So it goes far beyond just red, green, and blue. As PCs generally still work with specific BT.709 derived sRGB colour space, the RGB data from PC does not even directly control the monitor sub-pixels, but there is data processing to map that how to drive the reddish, greenish, and blueish subpixels in a way that the reproduced spectrum output actually matches the intended output defined by sRGB data.

Comment: There are also tunable lasers as perhaps another approach to using three monochromatic ones. I own a 25 mW tunable argon laser, for example. But I do not know of any, or any small-integer combination of same that could, in alternation, be used to cover the entire visible range. Another century from now, perhaps? So it would be back to what you write, the use of at least 3 monochromatic lasers. I doubt it's been attempted, though. (LED lasers are not monochromatic.) Direct answer though.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the technical difficulty of producing an accurately controlled spectrum at a fine resolution, your eye's color vision is based on three types of color-sensitive sensors, so it makes sense to stimulate those receptors even though the sensors are not exactly aligned to the light colors we can easily produce. (The color perception is at a lower resolution than brightness perception so there are savings to be had in transmission and storage of images and video, but leave that aside for now).

Keeping it simple, compare an n x m image where each pixel consists of 3 colors with resolution z bits for each. So you require n x m x z x 3 bits to store or transmit the image. If the image is '4K' and we have 14 bit resolution, that's 3,840 x 2,160 x 14 x 3 or about 41 megabytes to store one image without compression. Now imagine we split the spectrum into (only) 256 sections instead of 3 so each pixel is represented by an array of 256 x 14 bits (ideally each pixel is a two dimensional object representing the width of the visible spectrum on the X-axis and the amplitude on the Y axis, but 256 x 14 is an approximation). Now we need 3.5G bytes for an image that would look very, very similar to most people. Of course the two would *not* look the same to even a crude measuring instrument.

If you pass light from a 'white' LED through a prism you'll see something quite different from the broad spectrum white light from our sun.

Efficiency matters in engineering, especially when there are orders of magnitude difference in cost. That's likely why our eyes evolved to use only three color sensors (some animals have more apparently, so a bird of prey might find our television images unimpressive especially when showing things like mouse urine). Ours are mostly adequate to partially defeat camouflaged prey or predators and to help identify edible vs. non-edible plants, not to mention agonizing over subtly different paint chips at the hardware store.

Comment: Since you got into evolution in your last paragraph, I'd like to add that there are entire books on the topic of the evolution of eyes. It's kind of been a central topic in evolution circles ever since Darwin (and Wallace.) The book *Climbing Mount Improbable* (Richard Dawkins) spends most of its time on this topic in order to make still more important points about evolution. Very good answer, of course!

Comment: As a side note, in addition to animals, also some humans can be tetrachromats, as the reddish wavelength sensors are inherited via X chromosome, so you can have two different sets of redness sensors if you have two X chromosomes.

Comment: @Justme That means women. Interesting you bring this up. Because my wife was a *"color checker"* back in the day when 35mm film was printed on paper and sent back to purchasers. She was *very good* at it. The interesting thing she mentioned to me was that the company (Fred Meyer) used a suitcase full of ***tests*** to help determine who could be a color-checker, at all. She said to me that men almost NEVER passed these tests. Only women, some women, could. So, she told me, color-checkers were pretty much all women as a result. That was intriguing to me then. Thanks for your addition!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any particular **technical challenge**, as you can get LEDs of very many wavelengths and many kinds of white.

In lighting systems:

- You certainly see for example RGB+White to get better whites than the R+G+B would give.
- You often see "variant" RGB, where the colours are not the same as TV RGB colours, giving a different gamut.

But for LED pixel screens, there's an enormous **commercial challenge**: what portion of the market would want this, and how much are they prepared to pay for it?  In contrast to general purpose screens.

You do see epaper in, for example, black-white-red or black-white-yellow.  These systems work quite differently.

And you could use a [tunable laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunable_laser) with a scanning mechanism; but there are enormous materials science issues in getting the tunable range wide enough to make an RGB display.  Why you can't get wide enough range is a question for our friends at SE Physics.